# How do you backup your stock recovery from an unrooted Android device?

Tags: recovery-mode, stock-android, 5.1-lollipop, linux

#### TL;DR

Okay, so for the past month I have been researching how to do this, either on Windows or Linux..

I have yet to find a direct answer, or anything which is relevant.

I am a lot more comfortable doing this on Linux than I am on Windows, as I am a lot more familiar with Linux than Windows.

I'm relatively new to this whole thing(as well as Stack Exchange).

#### Question

If there is a relatively universal way of backing up your stock recovery from an ***unrooted*** Android device (on Snapdragon and MTK chipsets) that would probably be preferred, unless that is something that *is* dependent.

Comment: For backup of non-rooted devices with an MTK chipset, I've seen recommendation of [MTKDroidTools](http://www.mtkroms.com/2015/02/how-to-backup-and-restore-your-mtk.html) at some places.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Creating a .dd image of a Galaxy S3 without rooting the phone](http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/39872/creating-a-dd-image-of-a-galaxy-s3-without-rooting-the-phone)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Afraid there is no such thing:

- stock recovery itself doesn't offer any backup options
- other means of backing up a partition (and we're speaking about the `/recovery` partition here) always require root, as no other user has the required low-level access to file systems

Creating a real complete backup of a virgin device before attempting any system modifications (such as root, flashing custom recovery) is a hen-and-egg issue: you cannot create images of the device's partition without root – and the partition ends being "virgin" as soon as you root the device:

- to create images from partitions other than `/recovery`, you'd need a custom recovery (to run `dd` or do a [nandroid](/questions/tagged/nandroid) backup)
- to create an image of the (stock) `/recovery` partition, you'd need to root the device (in order to run `dd` from within the running Android system)

**To sum up:** if you want complete stock images, you'd need two similar devices. One you root to obtain the stock recovery – and the other you flash a custom recovery to obtain images of the other partitions. Hen and egg get a little bit smaller only, though, as in many cases<sup>1</sup> installing a custom recovery again requires a rooted device.

---

<sup>**1:** there are exceptions to that, but I can't give you a complete list. To my knowledge, e.g. Samsung [kies](/questions/tagged/kies) seems to permit flashing alternative ROMs and recoveries. Plus some stock devices seem to accept `update.zip` files to flash from recovery even if those are not signed with the manufacturer's key.</sup>